# C# WPF NumericUpDown Value Changed Event To Inform Which Row Has Been Modified

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, mahapps.metro, numericupdown

Thank you in advance for any assistance you may be able to provide!

I am working on a project which implements a C# WPF form using [MahApps NumericUpDown](https://mahapps.com/controls/numericupdown.html) targetting .NET Framework 4.6. A brief description of my application is that when a user presses a button on the form, data gets loaded into the DataGrid's ItemsSource (in the form of a List of custom Object) from the database based off the parameters on the form that they have configured (size, color, complexity, etc.).

My issue is of which when my NumericUpDown ValueChanged event handler is fired, I don't understand how to identify which DataGrid row in particular is being changed because when I handle my ValueChanged event, my DataGrid does not reflect the active row (SelectedIndex/Item), but rather it's null (every row in the DataGrid reflects another item that you wish to add to a cart, as such each row has an Item ID (text field), Item Description (text field), Item Quantity  (NumericUpDown), Item Price (text field based off of base price of item and Qty), Add To Cart (button), etc..

What I need to be able to do is update another control (text) in that particular DataGrid row when the NumericUpDown value is changed. The NumericUpDown control is responsible for the quantity of that particular item that you would like to have. Take for example this scenario: The NumericUpDown value is changed, I must update another column on that row to adjust for the total price based off of the quantity the user has adjusted the NumericUpDown value to (var totalPrice = NumericUpDown.Value * DbQueryResultsForCriteria.ItemPrice).

**Here is my NumericUpDown code from MainWindow.xaml**;
ItemResult is a list of my custom object, however I am unsure if I am implementing INotifyPropertyChanged correctly..

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="TotalQty">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                        <controls:NumericUpDown Name="Qty" ValueChanged="OnQtyChanged" Value="{Binding ItemResult, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

**ItemResult.cs**

```
public class ItemResultModel { }

public class ItemResult : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ItemResult()
    {
    }


    public ItemResult(string itemId, string itemName, decimal itemPrice)
    {
        ItemId = itemId;
        ItemName = itemName;
        ItemPrice = itemPrice.ToString("F");
    }

    public string ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    private string _itemQuantity;
    public string ItemQty
    {
        get => _itemQuantity;
        set
        {
            _itemQuantity = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(_itemQuantity));
        }
    }
    public string ItemPrice { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

}

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
       // The numeric up down control for the quanTITY has changed
    private void OnQtyChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double?> routedPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var item = ItemDataGrid.SelectedItem;       // returns null on the first run, otherwise returns the previously selected item
        var value = ItemDataGrid.SelectedValue;     // returns null on the first run, otherwise returns the previously selected value

    }
```

I feel so close to the solution! I apologize if I have left anything out that you may need.

***TLDR***: How do I figure out which row a NumericUpDown in a DataGrid has fired a ValueChanged event, so that I may update another column in that row?

**I was able to resolve this** by implementing [DataGridNumericUpDownColumn](https://mahapps.com/controls/datagrid.html#updown). For example, in my MainWindow.xaml I now have the following instead:

```
controls:DataGridNumericUpDownColumn Header="Qty" Minimum="1" HideUpDownButtons="False" Binding="{Binding ItemQty,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Thanks again, so much!

Comment: The question is, do you realy need to figure it out? 
As I can see, you have property `ItemQty` in your `ItemResult` class, couldn't you just use the property setter to recognize when was value changed?

Comment: sTrenat, thank you for your reply. Yes, I could use a setter to recognize when the NumericUpDown value has changed. However, to my knowledge this will not resolve the issue of not being able to determine which row in the DataGrid is selected (because selecting the NumericUpDown control doesn't necessarily select the row).

Comment: What do you want to do with selected rows?

Comment: I wanted to update another column in the "selected" row to reflect the total price based off the NumericUpDown value change (which is responsible for the total quantity). So to be clear, when the NumericUpDown is changed (quantity of item), update the total price text in that row.

I was able to fix this by replacing my DataGridTemplateColumn with [DataGridNumericUpDownColumn](https://mahapps.com/controls/datagrid.html#updown) (which was difficult to find as MahApps didn't make it clear that this control is available).

I'll update this post. Thanks sTrenat!